# Ajax request not working when signed in, works when not signed in

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an Ajax request that is simple like this:

```
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/admin.html",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
          if(data.error) {
            $('#alertt').text(data.error);
            $('#alertt').show();
            $('#alertt').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
          } else if (data.success) {
            var lati = $('#route_latitude').val();
            var longi = $('#route_longitude').val();
            increment();
            setMarker(lati, longi);
            $('#alertt').text(data.success);
            $('#alertt').show();
            $('#alertt').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
          }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          console.log(textStatus + " " + errorThrown)
        }
      })
```

The problem is, that if the user is signed in on the webpage, then it sits at `(pending)` for about 5 minutes then `500` errors, I'm not sure why this is, I'm using `Express v3` and this is basically how the request goes:

```
var isAdmin = function(req, res, next) {
  helper.isAdmin(req, res, next);
}
app.post('/admin.html', isAdmin, admin.new);



exports.isAdmin = function(req, res, next) {
  db.users.find({'rememberToken': req.cookies.rememberToken}, function(err, foundUser) {
    if (err) { console.log('We have an error' + err) } else {

      if (foundUser.length === 0) {
        console.log('Somebody attempted to view the Admin page without an account.')
        res.render('index', { 'title': 'Home Page'})
      } else if (foundUser[0].admin === 0) {
          console.log('A non-admin user account tried to log into the Admin page: ' + foundUser[0].email);
          res.render('index', { 'title': 'Home Page' });
      } else if (foundUser[0].rememberToken === req.cookies.rememberToken) {
        console.log('Admin viewing Admin page.');
          next();
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I really can't see anything wrong, yet for some reason it just sits at `(pending)` but if I do it not-logged in with no cookie set, (with the `isAdmin function` removed from the `post`) it works. Any help would be great this has been driving me nuts.

If you're curious how the sign in is handled: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f458783ffdc45255f85d/raw/dd59d045b7fa76abc2dca458eea16702477c36d1/gistfile1.js

This actually works completely as intended on localhost, but when I push it to Nodejitsu, it doesn't work and this problem happens.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you just visit the page directly in the browser (i.e. without using AJAX)?

Comment: The page loads fine, that Ajax is for a form on the administration page @Fenton

Comment: Which the page load goes through the same isAdmin check so the isAdmin has to be working

Comment: Does anything show in the console (in the terminal)? Cus if an error occurs at `if (err) { console.log('We have an error' + err) } else {` you don't send any response (no `.render()`or `.next()`. The same problem for you else-if clauses, depending on the data in you collection (which i know nothing about), is it possible that no one is true so that no res/next is executed when signed in?

Comment: Andreas has a point: when `foundUser` is an admin but `rememberToken` in the database differs from the one in `req.cookies`, your request gets stuck because you don't handle that situation.

Comment: You can also try to use `NODE_ENV=production npm start`. Nodejitsu runs with `NODE_ENV=production` by default, and you should have a start script setup that is compatible with `npm start` if you're deploying to Nodejitsu. It could be something with your application running under the development environment.